# MagickImage StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a frame data from to jpg with MagickImagCollection and I get an error StackOverFlowException.

The error throws it when creating the image collection of MagickImageCollection.

```
private void FrameCallBack(int streamId, IntPtr frameData, IntPtr userData)
        {
            if (_isPlayingStream)
            {
                var packet = Marshal.PtrToStructure<PacketInfo>(frameData);
                var size = (int)packet.PacketSize;

                switch (packet.PacketType)
                {
                    case 1:
                        var iBytes = new byte[size];
                        Marshal.Copy(packet.PacketBuffer, iBytes, 0, size);
                        LaunchNewFrameEvent(iBytes);
                        //CreateKeyFrame();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }



private void LaunchNewFrameEvent(byte[] frame)
    {
        var image = new MagickImageCollection(frame, new MagickReadSettings
        {
            Format = MagickFormat.Mp4,
            Height = 720,
            Width = 1280
        });

        var pictureBytes = image.LastOrDefault().ToByteArray(MagickFormat.Jpg);
    }
```

Comment: StackOverflowException refers to the Function Call Stack. It is basically Windows telling your Programmg: "I had to shut down that execution line, because you are recursing way to deep". Usually this indicates a infinite recursion. But just a very deep one can also cause it. I can not see any obvious case of recursion in this code, however. Please show and specify exactly wich line this happens on.

Comment: Merely the code snippet above won't help others reproduce the issue. ImageMagick has its own community https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/ where you might find previous discussions.

Comment: I get the array of bytes from the Hikvision SDK.
My theory is that the data is being sent damaged, because this only happens when it is recorded video, when it is live video if it processes the frames correctly